# How do you open the chest in Moerdred's room?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

It seems that there is no key in the sanitarium to open it and it says that you need the right key to open it.

Answer (score 3):

It's given to you during a quest, you can however wind up giving him the key, and never open the chest, but still finish the quest successfully.